# Xamarin's shared project issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to add a shared project to my ios/android solution. The problem is that after adding a reference to it and using a class from it, I get **CS0234** error (The type or namespace name "myname space" does not exist in the namespace...). I use Xamarin studio 5.0.1 for Mac. Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like you have invalid characters in your namespace.

Comment: No, intellisence highlits the code as correct

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I'm using Starter Edition
I've noticed erratic/buggy behaviour of Xamarin Studio(XS) while while refactoring Shared projects.
for example, when a working(*) Type/class inside an Android project is moved to the Shared Project.
XS refuse to build(*1) the Android project with "Type not found".

Solution Attempts: 
    - Clean/Rebuild does not help.
    - right-click reference and click Refresh,it does Not help.
    - Unload-Reload Shared Project (sometimes helps) (*2) .
    - Close Solution/Open Solution (sometimes Helps *2b). (more often)
    - Close XS Open XS (99% of the time helps)
    - Rename (*3) NameSpace in Shared Project Type/class helps 99% of the time (*4) (*5)

*: It builds
*1: Build failed
*2: Sometimes makes more damage than Help,
*3: Not Refactoring

4*: difficult to know if you didn't break it your self with the renaming when it didn't help , :)
5*: you need to go back to calling/referencing code and fiddle around a bit , intellisense will help you to find the right reference again (*6)

6*: Highly recommended to enable source analysis of open files (Resharper Mode :)

The Shared project feature is quite new so I'll expect it to get more 'stable' very soon. 
To be fair and almost out of context, I also notice glitches in Visual Studio with Shared projects 
When working  Microsoft projects like in Win8.1/Phone scenario.